# Pandas groupby and sum are dropping numeric columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Python/Pandas code:

```
standardized_df = get_somehow()
standardized_df['TermDaysAmountProduct'] = standardized_df['TermDays'] * standardized_df['Amount']
standardized_df['DaysToCollectAmountProduct'] = standardized_df['DaysToCollect'] * standardized_df['Amount']
logger.info("standardized_df cols are {}".format(standardized_df.head()))

grouped_df = standardized_df.groupby(["Customer ID"], as_index=False).sum()
logger.info("grouped_df cols are {}".format(grouped_df.head()))
```

When this runs it produces the following logs:

```
standardized_df cols are   Customer ID      Customer Name  ... TermDaysAmountProduct DaysToCollectAmountProduct
grouped_df cols are   Customer ID  Amount
```

So apparently during the groupby, the `TermDaysAmountProduct` and `DaysToCollectAmountProduct` columns (which are both numeric and *should* be summed) are getting removed for some reason. How can I keep these columns in the dataframe *after* the sum?

Comment: I suggest using `print(standardized_df.dtypes)` to check.

Comment: This isn't an [mcve]. I suspect that somewhere in your actual code you're assigning those columns to a different df somehow,which could just be a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn't noticed about pandas before that it drops non-numeric columns when applying sums. Interesting. Anyway, a workaround is to supply the column names manually to an `aggregate` function.

```
grouped_df = standardized_df.groupby(["Customer ID"], as_index=False).aggregate({<col_1>: sum, <col_2>: sum})
```

In general you can always apply an `aggregate({foo: bar})` to a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object where `foo` is column name and `bar` is a function that takes a `pd.Series` argument.

Note, If you have some large number of columns and you want them all to be summed without having to type out a big long dictionary, you can always prepare the aggregate dictionary. `aggregates = {col: sum for col in df.columns}`